# Any way to define iteration order for trove's TIntHashSet or TIntIntHashMap?

Tags: java, iterator, trove4j

Can I somehow define the iteration order of the elements from Trove's [TIntHashSet](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/index.html?gnu/trove/set/hash/TIntHashSet.html) ?

Or  are any other primitive `Set` that allows for defining the order of iteration of elements. I want  to iterate the elements in the insertion order or just same order as of the array that was used for construction of set.

Comment: Most HashCollections don't have a order. I would suggest updating a TIntArrayList to record the order.

Answer (score 0):

See java.util.LinkedHashMap, it preserve insertion order.